# Null Space and rotation of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A =

\begin{bmatrix}1/4&\sqrt3/4\\\sqrt3/4&3/4\end{bmatrix}

(a) Show that for each x ∈ R, Ax is the projection of x onto the line passing through the origin making an angle of 60 degrees with the positive x-axis.

(b) Show that null(A) is the line passing through the origin making an angle of 30 degrees with the negative x-axis.

(c) Show that null(A) = row(I − A).

For part a - I created an Ax augmented matrix, but after reducing the matrix I'm not sure how to determine that the lines formed make an angle of 60 degrees.

Part b - How would I find the null space of the matrix when the reduced form of A doesn't have any free variables?

Part c - I can't really prove part c since I'm not sure how to find the null space or row space of I-A.

Comment: For part b — sure it does. The second row of the rref of A is zero.

Comment: For part a — the slope of the line is that tangent of the angle it makes with the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

$$ Ax = \begin{bmatrix}1/4&\sqrt3/4\\\sqrt3/4&3/4\end{bmatrix}  
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}  =
\frac 14\begin{bmatrix}x+\sqrt 3 y\\\sqrt 3 x + 3 y\end{bmatrix} $$

$$=\frac {x+\sqrt 3 y}4\begin{bmatrix}1\\\sqrt3 \end{bmatrix} 
$$

if $Ax=0 $ then $x=-\sqrt 3 y$